# NIC behaviour in bridged adaptor mode

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, network-programming, virtual-machine, linux-device-driver

I was always in impression that, NIC card has unique MAC address and if incoming packet matches with that MAC, it lifts the packet and sends to kernel.
Recently when I have installed VMbox(host - Ubuntu, guest OS - Ubuntu) and configured network option with "bridge adapter" mode(MAC is randomly chosen), Vmbox is acting like a independent machine. I mean VM box OS has it's own MAC address and public IP.
I have observed that packets send on wire from VM box have virtual MAC & same for incoming packets.

1) Does NICs allow to send network packet with MAC id different from physical MAC id? and same for incoming packets, is it ok to lift packets where MAC is not matching with physical MAC id?( As I understand this is only possible in promiscuous mode)

2) Is n't it security violation? how about flooding internet by allocating more MACs by creating multiple instances of VM on many machines?

3) If MAC id is chosen randomly, there can be possibility that MAC id will be matching with with some other network device, how is this addressed?

Thank You,

Gopinath.

Comment: "_how about flooding internet by allocating more MACs by creating multiple instances of VM on many machines?_" MAC addresses are layer-2 addresses in the layer-2 header, which is stripped off and discarded by routers. A MAC address is only valid or seen on the LAN local to the host with the MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

1) Regular NICs operate on Layer-1, it is responsibility of OS (and respective kernelspace or userspace drivers) to provide valid Ethernet frame, using (if needed) vendor-related MAC address stored (for reference) in network card's memory. Whether the frame comes from host OS or from guest OS (through virtual switch in hypervisor) is irrelevant. The situation becomes slightly different in case of NFV and smart NICs, but not much.

The whole point of virtualization is that you shouldn't tell the difference from running your OS on virtual server or on standalone machine standing next to your host (looking either from the inside of your system or from the outside).

2) No, security don't get worse through that. As mentioned in previous point, the situation would be similar if you put physical host next to another. And from the security point of view, it's easier to flood local network with packets with forged source MAC than to instantiate the same number of VMs.

3) Collisions affect local network the same way as with regular host. The possibility is always there, but the probability is extremely low, with 6*8-1 bits to chose random address from. I've seen only one such collision, and only because MACs were set manually, not picked randomly.